# How to reference all objects of a class?

Tags: python, class, oop, pygame

I'm making a 2D game using pygame. I'm pretty new to python object oriented programming and don't quite understand classes and objects in full, so my coding approach might be a little weird. I have a player and entity class, and a key listener to change the player x and y (actually the background picture's x/y coords) relative to keys pressed. Currently, I have only one entity object named monster, because in order to properly move the player, I need to move every entity as well or else the entities will just move along with the player.
**How do I reference every single entity I create simultaneously so I can change their x and y values, so I don't have to reference them one by one in the key listener functions?**
Is there some entity.objects.all() sort of thing? Thank you if somebody can help, here's my code.

````
import os
import time
import threading
p.init()
c = p.time.Clock()


SCREEN_W = 800
SCREEN_H = 600
w = p.display.set_mode((SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H))
p.display.set_caption("Mason's Game")



walkRight = [p.image.load('game/r1.png'), p.image.load('game/r2.png'), p.image.load('game/r3.png'), p.image.load('game/r4.png'), p.image.load('game/r5.png'), p.image.load('game/r6.png'), p.image.load('game/r7.png'), p.image.load('game/r8.png'), p.image.load('game/r9.png')]
walkLeft = [p.image.load('game/l1.png'), p.image.load('game/l2.png'), p.image.load('game/l3.png'), p.image.load('game/l4.png'), p.image.load('game/l5.png'), p.image.load('game/l6.png'), p.image.load('game/l7.png'), p.image.load('game/l8.png'), p.image.load('game/l9.png')]
bg = p.image.load('game/bg.jpg')
char = p.image.load('game/standing.png')
mob = p.image.load('game/mob.png')
health = [p.image.load('game/h0.png'), p.image.load('game/h1.png'), p.image.load('game/h2.png'), p.image.load('game/h3.png'), p.image.load('game/h4.png'), p.image.load('game/h5.png'), p.image.load('game/h6.png'), p.image.load('game/h7.png'), p.image.load('game/h8.png'), p.image.load('game/h9.png'), p.image.load('game/h10.png'),]


def delay(x):
    later = p.time.get_ticks() + x
    if p.time.get_ticks() >= later:
        pass




class entity(object):
    def __init__(self, spawnx, spawny, x,y, level, health):


        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.spawnx = spawnx
        self.spawny= spawny
        self.velocity=14
        self.level = level
        self.health = health
        self.dead = False

    def draw(self, w):
        w.blit(mob, (self.x,self.y))

    def printCoords(self):
        print('x: ' , (-1*(m.x - monster.x) - 3600) - 300, " y: ", ((-1*(m.y - monster.y) - 3700) - 300)*-1)
    



    def pace(self):
        reachedRight = False
        reachedLeft = False

        if not reachedRight:
            self.x += self.velocity/10
            if self.x >= (self.spawnx + 100):
                reachedRight = True        
        if reachedRight:
            self.velocity *= -1
        if self.x <= (self.spawnx - 100):
            reachedLeft = True

        if reachedLeft:
            self.velocity*=-1   
    def stop(self):
        self.velocity = 0

    def followPlayer(self, player):

        #if (abs(ogre.x - monster.x)) < 160 or (abs(ogre.y - monster.y)) < 160:
           # monster.attackPlayer()

        #if monster is left of player, close enough, but not too close
        if self.x < player.x - 128 and self.x > player.x - 400:
            self.velocity = 5
            self.x += self.velocity
        #if monster is right of player, close enough, but not too close
        elif self.x > player.x + 128 and self.x < player.x + 400:
            self.velocity = -5
            self.x += self.velocity
        #if monster is south of player, close enough, but not too close
        if self.y < player.y - 128 and self.y > player.y - 400:
            self.velocity = 5
            self.y += self.velocity
        #if monster is north of player, close enough, but not too close
        elif self.y > player.y + 128 and self.y < player.y + 400:
            self.velocity = -5
            self.y += self.velocity

    def attackPlayer(self, player):
        def hitPlayer():
            if player.health > 0:
                player.sethealth(player.health - 1)
            else:
                player.death()
        t=threading.Timer(5.0,hitPlayer)
        t.start()



        
    


class mapp(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x= -3600
        self.y= -3700
        self.velocity = 14
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.standing = True

    def draw(self, w):
        w.blit(bg, (self.x,self.y))
        

class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 14
        self.j = False
        self.jc = 10
        self.right = False
        self.left = False
        self.walk = 0
        self.standing = True
        self.health = 10
        self.travX = (-3600 - m.x)
        self.travY = (-3700 - m.y)



    def respawn(self):
        time.sleep(0.4)
        monster.x = (-1*(m.x - monster.x) - 3600)
        monster.y = (-1*(m.y - monster.y) - 3700)
        m.x += (-3600 - m.x)
        m.y += (-3700 - m.y)
        #monster.y += (-1*(m.y - monster.y) - 3700)



    def death(self):
        self.sethealth(10)
        self.respawn()

        
        
    def sethealth(self, x):
        self.health = x

    def draw(self,w):

        w.blit(health[self.health], (730, 20))

        if self.walk + 1 >= 27:
            self.walk = 0

        if not(self.standing):
            if self.left:
                 
                w.blit(walkLeft[self.walk//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walk += 1
            elif self.right:
                w.blit(walkRight[self.walk//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walk += 1
        else:
            if self.left:
                w.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x,self.y))
            else:
                w.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x,self.y))


def drawGame():
    
    m.draw(w)
    ogre.draw(w)
    monster.draw(w)
    monster.followPlayer(ogre)



    p.display.update()




####### main ############
m = mapp(-3600,-3700)
ogre = player(400, 300, 64, 64)
monster = entity(-200, 600, -200, 600, 5, 100)
monster2 = entity(-300, 630, -300, 630, 5, 100)
####### main ############


run = True

while run:
    c.tick(27)
    for event in p.event.get():
        if event.type == p.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    k = p.key.get_pressed()
                
    #monster.printCoords()

    
    ### left right up down player ####
    if k[p.K_a]:
        monster.x +=m.velocity
        monster.spawnx+=m.velocity
        m.x+=m.velocity
        ogre.left = True
        ogre.right = False
        ogre.standing = False
    elif k[p.K_d]:
        monster.x -=m.velocity
        monster.spawnx-=m.velocity
        m.x-=m.velocity
        ogre.right = True
        ogre.left = False
        ogre.standing = False
    elif k[p.K_w]:
        monster.y +=m.velocity
        monster.spawny+=m.velocity
        m.y+=m.velocity
        ogre.right = False
        ogre.left = False
        ogre.standing = True
    elif k[p.K_s]:
        monster.y -=m.velocity
        monster.spawny-=m.velocity
        m.y-=m.velocity
        ogre.right = False
        ogre.left = False
        ogre.standing = True
    elif k[p.K_j]:
        #monster.attackPlayer()
        ogre.death()
    else:
        ogre.standing = True
        ogre.walk = 0

    

    drawGame()
    
    
p.quit()```
````

Comment: *"How do I reference every single entity I create simultaneously so I can change their x and y values, so I don't have to reference them one by one in the key listener functions? "* - Create a list of entities and move them in a `for`-loop

Answer (score 1):

Set the variables `move_x` and `move_y` dependent on the pressed key:

```py
move_x = 0
move_y = 0
if k[p.K_a]:
    move_x = m.velocity
    # [...]

elif k[p.K_d]:
    move_x = -m.velocity
    # [...]

elif k[p.K_w]:
    move_y = m.velocity
    # [...]

elif k[p.K_s]:
    move_y = -m.velocity
    # [...]
```

Create a list of monsters:

```py
monsters = [
    entity(-200, 600, -200, 600, 5, 100)
    entity(-300, 630, -300, 630, 5, 100)
]
```

Move each individual monster in a `for` loop:

```py
for monster in monsters:
    monster.x += move_x
    monster.y += move_y
    monster.spawnx += move_x
    monster.spawny += move_y
```

---

application loop:

```py
m = mapp(-3600,-3700)
ogre = player(400, 300, 64, 64)

monsters = [
    entity(-200, 600, -200, 600, 5, 100)
    entity(-300, 630, -300, 630, 5, 100)
]

run = True
while run:
    c.tick(27)
    for event in p.event.get():
        if event.type == p.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    k = p.key.get_pressed()
            
    ### left right up down player ####
    move_x = 0
    move_y = 0
    if k[p.K_a]:
        move_x = m.velocity
        ogre.left = True
        ogre.right = False
        ogre.standing = False
    elif k[p.K_d]:
        move_x = -m.velocity
        ogre.right = True
        ogre.left = False
        ogre.standing = False
    elif k[p.K_w]:
        move_y = m.velocity
        ogre.right = False
        ogre.left = False
        ogre.standing = True
    elif k[p.K_s]:
        move_y = -m.velocity
        ogre.right = False
        ogre.left = False
        ogre.standing = True
    elif k[p.K_j]:
        #monster.attackPlayer()
        ogre.death()
    else:
        ogre.standing = True
        ogre.walk = 0

    for monster in monsters:
        monster.x += move_x
        monster.y += move_y
        monster.spawnx += move_x
        monster.spawny += move_y
    m.x += move_x
    m.y += move_y

    drawGame()
```